# Core Data edit value with multiple entities

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift2

i am new to core data and swift, i have this multiple entity in one row like

```
 let sceneObj = Scene(entity: entityDescription!,
                                           insertIntoManagedObjectContext: DbHelper .getContext())

                sceneObj.createdAt = String(dictionary!["createdAt"]!)


                let appActionsDict = dictionary!["appActions"]! as? NSArray;

                for appActionsArray in appActionsDict!{
                    let entityDescription1 =
                        NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AppActions",
                                                          inManagedObjectContext: DbHelper .getContext())

                    let AppActionsObj = AppActions(entity: entityDescription1!,
                                         insertIntoManagedObjectContext: DbHelper .getContext())

                    AppActionsObj.action = appActionsArray["action"] as! NSNumber?

                    sceneObj .addObject(AppActionsObj)
                    }
```

Here if you see  i have "Scene" entity and "AppActions" where "AppAction" object is added to "Scene" object.

This add part works fine but i am stucked with the edit part of the same.

I have done this

```
 let fetchedResults = try DbHelper .getContext().executeFetchRequest(req) as! [Scene]

            if fetchedResults.count > 0 {
                for i in 0 ..< fetchedResults.count {


                    let managedObject = fetchedResults[i]

                    managedObject.setValue( String(dictionary!["createdAt"]!), forKey: "createdAt") } }
```

And i don't get how to edit "AppActions" in this.

Please guide me how to edit this.

Thanks in advance